# Python RegEx Comma Delim

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to split a comma delimited string using the following code. The regex code for comma-delimited is used in one of my online courses. I am trying to understand the following regex with lookaround how it works but couldn't get it completely. Can someone let me know how it works?

I know ?: is for non-capturing group and ?= is for look ahead but not sure how it works in the current context.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r',(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)')
text = 'tarcac,"this is, test1","this is, test2", 123566, testdata'
results= re.split(pattern, text)
for r in results:
   print(r.strip())
```

Output is

```
tarcac
"this is, test1"
"this is, test2"
123566
testdata
```

Comment: You regex is splitting on comma outside double quotes

Comment: thanks anubhava.. may i know why i need this (?:[^"]*"[^"]*") and why not simply this (?:"[^"]*")

Comment: Because lookahead has to count even number of quotes ahead to make sure splitting comma is outside the quotes.

Comment: Never use this regex in production, it is too inefficient and may freeze your code. In Python, there is a built-in CSV parser, use it.

Comment: thanks Wiktor... wil try that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break this down.

1. We are trying to look for commas which are separating parts of a string. So first we need to look for a comma

   - `,`
2. Now we need to look ahead to make sure this comma is not within a pair of quotation marks. We look ahead with `(?=...)`

   - We are looking for the first `"` so we can match as many non-quotes as possible. (we use `^"` to indicate any character that is note a quotation mark) `[^"]*`, and then we look for the first quote, together this makes:

     - `[^"]*"`
   - If we have matched the first quote, we need to look for the second. There can be any number of non-quote characters (`[^"]*`) between them, so we repeat

     - `[^"]*"`
   - We want to match any two pairs of quotes as many times as possible (without capturing), so we look for zero to infinite occurrences of quoted strings

     - `(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*`
   - Together this makes: `(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*)`
3. Finally we want to match any remaining non-quote characters, and then we wish to match the end of the string (indicated by `$`)

   - `[^"]*$`

Together all of this gives
 `,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)`

Essentially it is trying to match a comma by checking that every quote `"` character after the comma, can be paired with a closing quote character. This is why the output doesn't spereate the comma within `"this is, test1"` and `"this is, test2"`

Comment: perfect Jabob, got it